# Can we sync SharePoint online (office 365) with outlook calendar(desktop & online)?

Tags: sharepoint, outlook, office365, sharepoint-online

Can we sync SharePoint online (office 365)

with outlook calendar(desktop & online)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, SharePoint allows you to sync the Calendar {SharePoint web parts (lists)} to your Outlook along with other Web Parts like Tasks,Contacts,Discussion Board,Document Library.
Refer to the Following link if you need further Info.
https://sharepointmaven.com/sync-sharepoint-with-outlook/

Comment: No, I don’t want this. I need to read the events from the online calendar (and emails) in my SharePoint online.